# c# - Foreach a list and give a value each time in different label for example

Tags: c#, list

Convert my problem in very simple one. Let's say I have a string list and I want to foreach the list and in each loop will give the string value to different labels. I have 10 item in list and 10 label. Label1, Label2, Label3...... How can I loop and give the value in each label? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try? Can you show your code?

Comment: Write a for each loop. use string concatenation with variable . try by your self

Comment: Nothing yet coz like I said I don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: Then you need to learn how to write loops. Stackoverflow is for helping solve coding problems, not write them for you. Please take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in and if you still have problems come back, post a new question, and add what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly keep this simple by doing this:

```
var labels = new[]
{
    Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4, Label5,
    Label6, Label7, Label8, Label9, Label10
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    labels[i].Text = items[i];
}
```

It's strongly-typed and ensures that your values get assigned to the labels in the order that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming WinForms...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> values = new List<string>(new string[] {"cats", "dogs", "fish", "lizard" });
    for(int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
    {
        Control match = this.Controls.Find("label" + (i + 1).ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault();
        if (match != null)
        {
            match.Text = values[i];
        }
    }
}
```